# How to log in to MySQL shell when the user has no password?

Tags: permissions, login, mysql, authentication, database

I got this error:

```
root@sys3026:/home/sys3026# mysql --user=root --password    
Enter password:     
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any one please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure to check this step by step tutorial as well. It offers some more insights that the official guide does not. I hope it helps. Reference:
https://scalegrid.io/blog/how-to-set-up-mysql-digitalocean/

Answer (score 4):

When a MySQL user is configured to use `auth_socket` (instead of `mysql_native_password`), as it is by default in Ubuntu 18.04, you can log-in as root (for example) in the following way:

```
sudo mysql -u'root'
```

or just:

```
sudo mysql
```

References:

- [Digital Ocean: How To Install MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04 - read Step 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 3):

If your database has no password, just leave out the `--password` parameter.

```
$ mysql --user=root
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843973/mysql-is-prompting-for-password-even-though-my-password-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

If you have forgotten your password or you can not login you can always run mysql in a "safe_mode". Which allows you to access it without any password restriction - to change the root password or adjust something else if something went wrong.

```
systemctl stop mysql
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Now you can access the mysql server without a password.

```
mysql -uroot
```

Add a new password to the root user in the mysql shell

```
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("newpassword") where User='root';
flush privileges;
```

Now restart it in normal mode again and it will work with the new password.

```
systemctl stop mysql
systemctl start mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

This is the command to run mysql when no password is set, But If you just installed it and you did not set any password, I am pretty sure it still has a random password that can be found in logs located in `/var/log/mysql`.

`mysql -u root`

Answer (score 0):

**`sudo mysql -e "CREATE USER $USER"` to do further logins without `sudo`**

You can also create a user for yourself without setting a password:

```
sudo mysql -e "CREATE USER $USER"
```

and from now on you can login directly with:

```
mysql
```

This works based on the same principle as why `sudo mysql` works for `root` as mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/a/1129495/52975: if the password is not set, it seems to automatically try and authenticate by Linux username.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create the user `john` with no password as shown below:

```
CREATE USER 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```
CREATE USER 'john'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

Then, you can log in with no password as shown below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) says `MYSQL_PWD is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line/77467429#77467429) explains how to log in to MySQL without a password prompt:

```
mysql -u john
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john --password=''
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u john
```

Or, you can log in with no password for the password prompt as shown below:

```
mysql -u john -p
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john --password
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u john -p
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u john --password
Enter password:
```

Or on Windows, you can set the user `john` and no password under `[client]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[client]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448967/is-it-possible-to-store-a-password-in-my-ini-file/77466171#77466171) explains how to log in with `my.ini`:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="john"
password=""
```

Or:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="john"
# password=""
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below:

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

*Not setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` gets error as shown below:

```
mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```